# bash, awk and or sed to clean up string with special formatting

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed

Within a script I am working on, I have to clean up a string to the format I need.

Structure of every string: (zip code, street name, number, extension):

- 4 digits, 2 letters (zip code) If no match, no result
- string of characters (street name)can have any kind of character
- string of digits (number)

Eventually followed by

- string of characters (extension) can have any kind of character and is not always there. When a digit, it is separated from the number by a dash, a space or something else

The resulting string should be
4 digits, 2 letters, the number and in case of an extension followed by x and the letter or digit of the extension

Below some examples:

- **1019RX**Javakade**254** -result: **1019RX254**
- **1019PG**Bogortuin**50** -result: **1019PG50**
- **1079TH**Eemsstraat**34**-**II** -result: **1079TH34xII**
- **1066EC**1eLouwesweg6 -result: **1066EC6**
- **1019LC**KNSM-laan193 -result: **1019LC193**
- **1019WZ**Scheepstimmermanstraat**74** -result: **1019WZ74**
- **2288EA**SirWinstonChurchillaan**275**-**F126** -result: **2288EA275xF126**
- **1056HZ**MaartenHarpertszoonTrompstraat**12**-**3hg** -result: **1056HZ12x3hg**
- **1092GR**Laing'snekstraat**15G** -result: **1092GR15xG**
- F-30700RueduLavoir1 -result: **nothing**

I started with

```
echo "1019RXJavakade254" | awk '{print substr($0,0,6)}'
```

to get the zip code
and after that I think I should use a "print match", but I can't get it right from there.

The strings are passed individually and used in the next step of the script. Originally they come from a csv file, but the (combination of) column(s) the string is coming from is always different. The first part of the script is handling that and creates this source string. The resulting string will be placed back in a column which I can add as the last column to the original csv file

I'm aware of the problems regarding numbers after the first 6 characters and if an extension is present. So in my opinion the workflow should be something like: First 6 characters should be 4 digits, 2 letters, if not total result is empty. Skip character 7 and 8 and grab the first group of digits you encounter after character 8, that is the number and everything else after that is the extension. The extension never starts directly with a digit. Only in case of an extension there is an x in between. The extension should be stripped of other then alphanumeric characters.

This should cover the most, the rest will have a delay in delivery :)

---

## Solved

**@kvantour** Thanks for your answer. I slightly changed the code to get the non capital letters too. The result is part of a larger applescript which runs unattended on a Xserve here in the company.
So the code I use now is

```
set KixCodeSourceClean to do shell script "echo " & KixCodeSource & " | awk '/^[0-9]{4}[a-zA-Z]{2}.+[0-9]+[- ].+$/{match(substr($0,8),/[0-9]+[- ].+$/);s=substr($0,7+RSTART,RLENGTH); sub(/[- ]/,\"x\",s);print substr($0,1,6)s;next} /^[0-9]{4}[a-zA-Z]{2}.+[0-9]+[a-zA-Z].*$/{match(substr($0,8),/[0-9]+[a-zA-Z].*$/);s=substr($0,7+RSTART,RLENGTH);match(s,/[0-9]+/);print substr($0,1,6)substr(s,1,RLENGTH)\"x\"substr(s,RLENGTH+1);next} /^[0-9]{4}[a-zA-Z]{2}.+[0-9]+$/{ match(substr($0,8),/[0-9]+$/);s=substr($0,7+RSTART);print substr($0,1,6)s;next}'"
```

It works perfectly and is a oneliner, which I prefer in this case. I use this method a lot. Jumping in and out Applescript and use the unix shell to solve things faster.

Comment: Are these strings variables passed to your script individually or do they come from a file, all at once (e.g. each on a separate line)?

Comment: The strings are passed individually and used in the next step.

Comment: Problems occur with names such as "1066EC1eLouwesweg6-F"

Comment: You need to be more specific about the extension. You say it is separated "by a dash, a space or something else", but I have a feeling that this "something else" is going to be a source of problems.

Comment: @TomFenech Also don't forget his penultimate example, which shows an extention witout anything.

Comment: @Tom and Kvantour I'm aware of the problems regarding numbers after the first 6 characters and if an extension is present. So in my opinion the workflow should be something like: First 6 characters should be 4 digits, 2 letters, if not total result is empty. Skip character 7 and 8 and grab the first group of digits you encounter after character 8, that is the number and everything else after that is the extension. The extension never starts directly with a digit. Only in case of an extension there is an x in between. The extension should be stripped of other then alphanumeric characters.

Comment: @user6802941 I suggest that you edit this information into your question to make it as clear as possible.

Comment: @JBVeenstra don't forget _Sint Vitusholt 2e Laan_ in Windschoten and _A_ in Ottoland. Skipping the first two might not solve the problem.

Comment: [edit] your question to provide concise, testable sample input and expected output in a format where we can just copy/paste them to test a potential solution without having to edit them to remove formatting, etc. Use the editors `{}` button to format correctly (or indent each line 4 chars manually).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea I had in mind was an exclusion principle in which we test one-possibility after another:

1. Addresses of the form `NNNNXXabc123efgMMM-SUF` and `NNNNXXabc123efgMMM SUF`
2. Addresses of the form `NNNNXXabc123efgMMMSUF`
3. Addresses of the form `NNNNXXabc123efgMMM`

The problem, however, is that `SUF` can be anything and `abc123efg` can be anything. As a consequence, the example "1066EC1eLouwesweg6" will match the second case.

To avoid this, I was thinking to have a look at the conditions for street names, but in the Netherlands, these can be anything:

- *Ir. Mr. Dr. van Waterschoot van der Grachtstraat* in Heerlen (just long)
- *Marga Klompélaan* and *Groot-Brittanniëstraat* in Nijmwegen (diacritics)
- *1e en 2e Anjeliers-dwarsstraat* in Amsterdam (starting with numbers)
- *Sint Vitusholt 2e Laan* in Winschoten (numbers in the middle)
- *'s-Gravelandseweg* in Hilversum (starting with a `'`)
- *A* and *B* in Ottoland (just too short)

So there is not even a condition on the length of the street name, except, if it is one character long, it is a letter.

So this gave me the following AWK:

```
{gsub(/\r/,"",$0)}  # removes `\r` if any
/^[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][A-Z][A-Z].+[0-9]+[- ].+$/{match(substr($0,8),/[0-9]+[- ].+$/);s=substr($0,7+RSTART,RLENGTH); sub(/[- ]/,"x",s);print substr($0,1,6)s;next}
/^[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][A-Z][A-Z].+[0-9]+[a-zA-Z].*$/{match(substr($0,8),/[0-9]+[a-zA-Z].*$/);s=substr($0,7+RSTART,RLENGTH);match(s,/[0-9]+/);print substr($0,1,6)substr(s,1,RLENGTH)"x"substr(s,RLENGTH+1);next}
/^[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][A-Z][A-Z].+[0-9]+$/{ match(substr($0,8),/[0-9]+$/);s=substr($0,7+RSTART);print substr($0,1,6)s;next}
```

And on this input file:

```
1019RXJavakade254
1019PGBogortuin50
1079THEemsstraat34-II
1066EC1eLouwesweg6
1019LCKNSM-laan193
1019WZScheepstimmermanstraat74
2288EASirWinstonChurchillaan275-F126
1056HZMaartenHarpertszoonTrompstraat12-3hg
1092GRLaing'snekstraat15G
F-30700RueduLavoir1
```

It gave me the following output:

```
1019RX254
1019PG50
1079TH34xII
1066EC6
1019LC193
1019WZ74
2288EA275xF126
1056HZ12x3hg
1092GR15xG
```

As you notice, the last one is not matched!

However, I cannot assure you that this will work 100%.

> **fun fact:** In Ottoland, you can [travel from A to B](https://www.google.nl/maps/place/Ottoland/@51.8904645,4.8604753,18z) by crossing a bridge of 10m.

Answer (score 1):

Several requirement to extract the zip code and the extension, so pipeline the results to additional `sed` be deployed here.

```
$ str="1066EC1eLouwesweg6"
$ sed -r 's/(^[0-9]{4}[A-Z]{2})..[^0-9]*(.*)/\1\2/' <<< "$str" | sed 's/-/x/' | sed -r '/[^x]/ s/(.*[0-9]+)([A-Z]+$)/\1x\2/'
1066EC6
```

Brief explanation,

1. `sed -r 's/(^[0-9]{4}[A-Z]{2})..[^0-9]*(.*)/\1\2/' <<< "$str"`: filtered out the street name first.
2. `sed 's/-/x/'`: substitute the '-' to 'x' if exists
3. `sed -r '/[^x]/ s/(.*[0-9]+)([A-Z]+$)/\1x\2/'`: if the result until now doesn't exist 'x', add the 'x' between digits and alphabets.

Answer (score 1):

This (using GNU `awk` for the 3rd arg to `match()` and `gensub()`) will produce the expected output from the input you provided:

```
$ cat tst.awk
match($1,/^([0-9]{4}[[:alpha:]]{2})(..[^0-9]+)(.*)/,a) {
    if ( ! sub(/[^[:alnum:]]/,"x",a[3]) ) {
        a[3] = gensub(/([0-9])([[:alpha:]])/,"\\1x\\2",1,a[3])
    }
}
{
    tgt = (1 in a ? a[1] a[3] : "nothing")
    print tgt, (tgt == $NF ? "succ" : "fail")
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
1019RX254 succ
1019PG50 succ
1079TH34xII succ
1066EC6 succ
1019LC193 succ
1019WZ74 succ
2288EA275xF126 succ
1056HZ12x3hg succ
1092GR15xG succ
nothing succ
```

It will fail if a digit can appear in the street name anywhere other than the first 2 characters.

The above was run on this input file and prints succ/fail after every result based on whether or not the result matches the expected result from the last field of the input file:

```
$ cat file
1019RXJavakade254 -result: 1019RX254
1019PGBogortuin50 -result: 1019PG50
1079THEemsstraat34-II -result: 1079TH34xII
1066EC1eLouwesweg6 -result: 1066EC6
1019LCKNSM-laan193 -result: 1019LC193
1019WZScheepstimmermanstraat74 -result: 1019WZ74
2288EASirWinstonChurchillaan275-F126 -result: 2288EA275xF126
1056HZMaartenHarpertszoonTrompstraat12-3hg -result: 1056HZ12x3hg
1092GRLaing'snekstraat15G -result: 1092GR15xG
F-30700RueduLavoir1 -result: nothing
```